# Force SQL to Add Rather than Concatenate Two Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have column OFF_SAT_COMP.LINKACCT and OFF_SAT_COMP.COUNTRY. I am trying to add the values of these two columns in a given row together, but when I do so as follows:

```
(OFF_SAT_COMP.LINKACCT + OFF_SAT_COMP.COUNTRY)
```

It is concatenating rather than returning the sum of the two column values. e.g. It is returning 500300 where I want 800. How can I force it to use addition and not read the sign as concatenation? I'm guessing its auto-flipping to concatenation b/c one of the columns is returning as a string rather than an integer - but they are both truly integers (yes, this database is screwed up - no, I can't fix it...legacy/third-party).

Comment: How is it possible that SQL Server interprets int column value to a varchar? I think, that is the question here that I would like answer for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to cast the non-integer values

```
(Cast(OFF_SAT_COMP.LINKACCT As int) + Cast(OFF_SAT_COMP.COUNTRY As int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dave,

Cast one of the columns to integer

Select column1 + cast(column2 as integer)
from table